# Having issue to attach data to email (PHP), want to send data upto 20 MB, Any Guess?

Tags: php, email, pdf, base64, attachment

Facing issue : Try to send email using PHP up to 20 MB data as email attachment all files are .pdf files. I can successfully send a email up to 5 MB but if try send more data than 5 MB i never got email in my inbox and no error is shown by PHP. I have search about this issue on many forum and i try all the solutions they provided. Like settings in php.ini file.

php.ini Settigns :

memory_limit = 256M

max_execution_time = 60

max_file_uploads = 25

post_max_size = 25M

upload_max_filesize = 10M

Code i am using :

```
        $to = $settings->factoring_email; 
        $from = ucfirst($settings->company_name)."<".$settings->company_billing_email.">";

        $subject = ucfirst($settings->company_name).' Invoice Manifest '.$post['inv_date'];
        $message = "Please see attached documents.";
        $headers = "From: $from";

        // boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        // headers for attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        // multipart boundary
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

        // preparing attachments
        $count = count($files);
        for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
            if(stristr($files[$x],'manifest')) {
                $path = BASE_PATH.DS.'docs'.DS.'tmp'.DS.$files[$x];
                $name = $files[$x];
            }
            else {
                $path = BASE_PATH.DS.'docs'.DS.'load_info'.DS.$files[$x].'.pdf';
                $name = $files[$x].'.pdf';
            }

            if(file_exists($path)) {
                $file = fopen($path,"rb");
                $data = fread($file,filesize($path));
                fclose($file);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

                unset($file, $data);
            }
        }
        // send

        $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($ok) {
            echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
        }
```

Comment: Is that what your `PHP.ini` file has for the settings?

Comment: Which of the two messages after the `mail` call gets printed?

Comment: @fred: Yes those values are in php.ini file

Comment: @Oswald: This one : mail could not be sent!

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what does your form look like, or are you using one in the first place? If so, post it. Plus "PaulProgrammer" may have a point there. See what you can find out about that.

Comment: What message do you get if you `don't` attach a file? (Process of elimination). Have you tried that too? (Test all options).

Comment: @fred: No problem in form, i got all the files in $_FILES array and i can send mail with attachment upto 5 MB data. The problem is this when i try to attach more data say 8 MB i never got mail in my inbox and never got error from PHP and even i check server log no error in server log. I hope this helps a bit to understand my issue.

Comment: There's obviously something blocking the process when trying to send something over 5MB. There's no restriction in your form?

Comment: (Possible reason) I quote: "Email users can be puzzled by these limits because the MIME encoding adds 33% overhead – so that a 20MB document on disk exceeds a 25MB file attachment limit." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_attachment

Comment: @Jay Are you using `Phpmailer` library by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting smaller mail successfully sent, I'd wager it's more likely an issue with your mail service configuration.  Someone on your mail route isn't allowing "big" messages through. Check your reply-to address and see if any bounces are coming back.

Comment: Bounces shouldn't be comming back, because the call to `mail()` fails, which means the mail is not accepted for delivery.

Comment: I see that. So, the configuration is on the entry point -- local sendmail or exim or whatever.  Anyway, 10-20MB attachments are Bad Form.  Seriously suggest sending a link to a pickup box rather than an email attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You never recieve the email in your inbox, because the email is never sent on the way. The email is rejected either by the SMTP server, that the `mail()` function contacted, or by the program, that the `mail()` function spawned.

Which of these two is the case depends on your [mail-related PHP configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).